# Merge files in dataframe with new column name. Error

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a directory with txt files tab-delimited. The size of each one is around 200MB. What I want is to merge all files adding one extra column with the filename.

The code that I have used:

```
all_txt <- rbindlist(mapply(
  c,
  (
    list.files(
      path = "./",
      pattern = "*.vcf.gz.hg38_multianno.txt",
      full.names = TRUE
    ) %>%
      lapply(
        read.table,
        header = TRUE,
        sep = "\t",
        encoding = "UTF-8"
      )
  ),
  (
    list.files(
      path = "./",
      pattern = "*.txt",
      full.names = TRUE
    ) %>%
      basename() %>%
      as.list()
  ),
  SIMPLIFY = FALSE
),
fill = T)
```

When it starts, I get the following warnings and then an error:

```
Warning in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  number of items read is not a multiple of the number of columns
Warning in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string
Warning in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  number of items read is not a multiple of the number of columns
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 254480 did not have 145 elements
```

How I can identify the file that doesn't have 145 elements?

All files should contain 145 columns.

thanks!

Comment: try to use `data.table::fread` instead of `read.table`.  usually it works more fine even for txt files.

Comment: That's so great. I am running the script on the Rstudio server and is working (very slow, but working)

Answer (score 0):

As @islem mentioned, adding `data.table::fread` solved the issue.